# Firefox is slow to resolve localhost domains on MacOS, Chrome is not

Tags: firefox, virtualbox, dns, localhost

I am developing a website on localhost with the following entry in my hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10  mysite.local
```

That IP is coming from a Vagrant provisioned VM hosted in Virtualbox.

Whenever I try to load the site in Firefox, it takes about 3-4 seconds before it is able to resolve the domain. I see `looking up mysite.local` in the lower left of Firefox for a while, then it loads the site quickly. Each subsequent lookup happens quickly as if it has cached that DNS lookup,

However, if I let the site go idle for about 5 minutes, the lookup is slow again.

Chrome and Safari do not have this problem. They both always resolve the domain quickly, even from a cold start. Firefox is the only one that struggles with it.

What can I do to troubleshoot what might be causing this problem in Firefox?

EDIT: It looks like Firefox caches DNS lookups for 60 seconds (according to `about:config`, which explains why the site is resolved quickly if I continually use it, but goes back to being slow if I let it sit idle. So the question then becomes, why is only Firefox having trouble resolving it when it's not cached?

Comment: What is the response time of you open the Terminal and run `ping mysite.local` or even `curl -I mysite.local`? Also, what is the web server you are using on your VM? Apache? Nginx? Something else?

Comment: Response time for `ping mysite.local` is 0.3 seconds on average. Nginx is the webserver.

Comment: Do you have DNS over HTTPS enabled? Go to `about:preferences` and check the Network Settings at the bottom of General. Or go to `about:config` and check `network.trr.mode`.

Comment: @Bob No, it is disabled (I didn't set this, it was just that way when I checked the settings). Enabling it fixed the problem though! What are the security ramifications of enabling DNS over HTTPs?

Comment: That's... rather odd. I would expect this kind of problem if DNS over HTTPS is *enabled*, because it'll directly query a specific external DNS server (CloudFlare, by default) rather than use the local OS resolver, and therefore ignore `/etc/hosts`. In that scenario, *disabling* DNS over HTTPS would fix your issue. *Enabling* it, on the other hand, shouldn't... try disabling it again and see what happens? What specifically is `network.trr.mode` set to? (there's a "auto-pick fastest" and a "try doh but fallback on timeout" option, which is what I originally suspected was your issue)

Comment: I agree, it's odd. If I enable DNS over HTTPS via the UI in `about:preferences`, it sets `network.trr.mode` to 2 and shows as modified. If I disable the option via `about:preferences` it gets set to 0. Looks like maybe I spoke too soon. After disabling it, and then re-enabling it, I am having the same issue as before. The first time I enabled it, it did fix the problem.

Comment: And if you disable (on `0`) you experience this problem again? On `2` it should try DNS over HTTPS, fail to resolve this domain, and fall back to trying native - which I would've expected to introduce the delay you experience. On `0` it should be full native, without the delay.

Comment: Oddly, I now experience this problem again with both 0 and 2. The first time I enabled it, I did so via the UI. I don't know what the actual value was at that time, but it did fix the issue. It was only when I disabled it to test it, and then re-enable it, that it went back to being problematic. So as it stands now, both 0 and 2 exhibit the same problem. Very odd.

Comment: You may have just been within the cached period. Leave DNS over HTTPS off for now. Just for kicks, can you try a different TLD? One other than `.local`? I wonder if mDNS is involved. Try both a nonexistent one like `mysite.qwertyasdf` and a "real" one like `mysite.com`.

Comment: You can also poke around in `about:networking`, especially the "Logging" tab, and see if you can identify anything odd.

Comment: Instead of relying on editing your `/etc/hosts` file, I would recommend installing [Avahi deamon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon) on your VM and let it handle the mDNS. The hostname would be the machine name of the VM, FWIW. So if the machine is named `mysite` then `mysite.local` would work as expected.

Comment: @Bob I took your advice, and Firefox doesn't like .local as a domain. I used `.qwerty` and it worked fine. I created several dummy sites on that VM, some with `.local` and some with `.qwerty` and all of the `.local` domains were slow, while `.qwerty` was fast. `.com` would not work (it always tried to resolve actual internet domains for them). I used to use `.dev`, but Chrome killed that so I switched to `.local`, which Firefox hates. *Sigh*. Thanks for the help though. The resolution is to change the TLD to something FF friendly. If you want to create an answer for your comment, I'll accept.